# Chanlink Public CryptoGraphy

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

While chainlink creates a random number and more secure public cryptography algorithm, I recently came across the quantum resistive ledger concepts and resistive to a quantum computer with hash mesh etc. My question is whether the chainlink public cryptography algorithm is future quantum resistive hack proof based?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what 'quantum resistive hack proof' entails, but [here's](https://blog.chain.link/chainlink-vrf-on-chain-verifiable-randomness/) a fairly good technical walkthrough about how VRF works. Also, you can [have a look](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/tree/develop/contracts/src/v0.6) at the code yourself (look at the VRF contracts)